# Properly converting rows into columns using PIVOT in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, pivot

I've manage to pivot the existing rows into columns, however instead of producing 1 row, the pivot results in 2 rows with the same container. Here is my dataset.

```
SELECT distinct c.container, c.attribute, c.value, c.property from cars c
WHERE c.container = 'VOLVO'

---------------------------------------------------
| CONTAINER |  ATTRIBUTE |   VALUE   | PROPERTY |
|  VOLVO    |    TIRE    |   DUNLOP  |     A    |
|  VOLVO    |    SEATS   |     4     |     A    |
|  VOLVO    |    PRICE   |   25,000  |     B    |
|  VOLVO    |    COLOR   |    BLUE   |     A    |
|  VOLVO    |    MODEL   |    XC90   |     A    |


SELECT * FROM cars
PIVOT( max(value) for attribute IN ([TIRE],[SEATS],[PRICE],[COLOR],[MODEL])) P
WHERE container = 'VOLVO'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CONTAINER |  PROPERTY |    TIRE    | SEATS |   PRICE  |  COLOR  |  MODEL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| VOLVO     |     A     |   DUNLOP   |   4   |   NULL   |  BLUE   |  XC90
| VOLVO     |     B     |   NULL     |  NULL |  25,000  |  NULL   |  NULL
```

How would I merge those 2 rows and produce this result?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CONTAINER |  PROPERTY |    TIRE    | SEATS |   PRICE  |  COLOR  |  MODEL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| VOLVO     |     A     |   DUNLOP   |   4   |  25,000  |  BLUE   |  XC90
```

Thanks!

Comment: Leave property out of your query / don't use select *

Comment: i explicitly select the columns and it still produces the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leave out property:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  select CONTAINER, VALUE, ATTRIBUTE from cars
) S
PIVOT( max(value) for attribute IN ([TIRE],[SEATS],[PRICE],[COLOR],[MODEL])) P
WHERE container = 'VOLVO'
```

Result:

```
CONTAINER   TIRE    SEATS   PRICE   COLOR   MODEL
VOLVO       DUNLOP  4       25,000  BLUE    XC90
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb8b2/1)